How to test a custom route?
I have this route:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "my_profile", to: "users#show"
end

Which creates this route:
my_profile GET    /my_profile(.:format)   users#show

I can easily test the users#show action in UsersControllerTest but I would like to test that the custom route exists and executes the code on the action. Something like:
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def test_my_profile_route
    get "/my_profile"
    # Testing stuff
  end
end

But I get:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/my_profile", :controller=>"users"}


Testing that route is no different then testing any other route in Rails.
Instead the problem here is that you're using the old deprechiated controller tests (ActionController::ControllerTest) instead of an integration test (ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest).
Controller tests are superficially similiar but fundamentially different. Instead of a real HTTP request the get method dispatches the action directly on instance of the controller that is fed a faked request. Thus it was used with a symbol corresponding to the actual method name. This process is known to be extremely flawed and controller tests were long since relegated to legacy apps only.
def test_my_profile_route
  get :my_profile
end

The error No route matches {:action=>"/my_profile", :controller=>"users"} is because ActionController::ControllerTest tries to verify that the route exists by looking it up using the controller and action name. Note the forward slash.
Change the superclass of your tests to ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest and make sure you're using up to date tutorials/guides.
class UserProfileFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "can see the users profile" do
    # @todo sign in the user
    get "/my_profile"
    assert_select "h1", "Users#my_profile"
  end
end


Actually, I am using ActionController::TestCase (I have updated my question to clarify this) but it's the same case. I have created a special /test/integration/special_routes_test.rb with an ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest, as you suggested, to test file to cover all the special URLs and it works :)

@fguillen sorry - that was a typo on my part. I meant ActionController::TestCase.
